# In MongoDB how do you use $set to update a nested value/embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB how do you use **`$set`** to update a nested value?

For example, consider a collection **people** with the following document:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284"),
  name: "foo",
  address: { street: "123", town: "bar" }
}
```

How do I update the `street` field embedded in the `address` document from `"123"` to `"Main Street"`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Using the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
db.people.update({ }, { $set: { "address.street": "Main Street" } })
```

Comment: Does this work even if address does not exist? I know $set will create street if it doesn't exist on address but what is the behavior if the ancestral properties don't exist? Also, your link requires a login.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the heads-up about the link, I've fixed it. To answer your question: it will create the required ancestral properties for you if they don't exist.

Comment: @Tom Yes it will. It will create the whole object down to the field you're setting. (Late reply, but hopefully this is useful to others stumbling on this question)

Comment: How to set the same field if it address is an array. For Example : {
  _id: ObjectId("5a7e395e20a31e44e0e7e284"),
  name: "foo",
  address: [{ street: "123", town: "bar" }]
}

Comment: How can I use the existing values of an embedded array? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69494035/how-to-use-set-and-dot-notation-to-update-embedded-arraa-while-using-matching-a

Comment: is there another way to do this? in my case there is an update request with properties, and if possible i would like to skip converting all fields to dot notation which would require each field to be mentioned in my code again.

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK if the root node (`address`) is already set to `null` expilicitly. Updates would fail silently!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Niels' answer, also do verify the "type" of the nested value. In my case, it was a "string" formed from json. Though this might be unlikely, but do ensure that the value has the right type.