# How to use $set and dot notation to update embedded array elements using corresponding old element?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have following documents in a MongoDb:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(host='my_host', port=27017)
database = client.forecast
collection = database.regions
collection.delete_many({})
regions = [
    {
        'id': 'DE',
        'sites': [
            {
                'name': 'paper_factory',
                'energy_consumption': 1000
            },
            {
                'name': 'chair_factory',
                'energy_consumption': 2000
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 'FR',
        'sites': [
            {
                'name': 'pizza_factory',
                'energy_consumption': 3000
            },
            {
                'name': 'foo_factory',
                'energy_consumption': 4000
            },
        ]
    }
]
collection.insert_many(regions)
```

Now I would like to copy the property `sites.energy_consumption` to a new field `sites.new_field` for each site:

```
set_stage = {
    "$set": {
        "sites.new_field": "$sites.energy_consumption"
    }
}

pipeline = [set_stage]
collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

However, instead of copying the **individual** value per site, all site values are collected and **added as an array**. Intead of **'new_field': [1000, 2000]** I would like to get **'new_field': 1000** for the first site:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("61600c11732a5d6b103ba6be"),
    "id": "DE",
    "sites": [
      {
        "name": "paper_factory",
        "energy_consumption": 1000,
        "new_field": [
          1000,
          2000
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "chair_factory",
        "energy_consumption": 2000,
        "new_field": [
          1000,
          2000
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("61600c11732a5d6b103ba6bf"),
    "id": "FR",
    "sites": [
      {
        "name": "pizza_factory",
        "energy_consumption": 3000,
        "new_field": [
          3000,
          4000
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "foo_factory",
        "energy_consumption": 4000,
        "new_field": [
          3000,
          4000
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**=> What expression can I use to only use the corresponding entry of the array?**

Is there some sort of **current-index operator**:

```
$sites[<current_index>].energy_consumption
```

or an **alternative dot operator** (would remind me on difference between * multiplication and .* element wise matrix multiplication)?

```
$sites:energy_consumption
```

Or is this a bug?

*Edit*

I also tried to use the "$" [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), e.g. with

```
sites.$.new_field
```

or

```
$sites.$.energy_consumption
```

but then I get the error

```
FieldPath field names may not start with '$'
```

**Related:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#std-label-set-add-field-to-embedded

[In MongoDB how do you use $set to update a nested value/embedded document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828452/in-mongodb-how-do-you-use-set-to-update-a-nested-value-embedded-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is member of an array by selecting it you are selecting all of them.

```
{ar :[{"a" : 1}, {"a" : 2}]}

"$ar.a" = [1 ,2]
```

Also you cant mix update operators with aggregation, you cant use things like
`$sites.$.energy_consumption`, if you are doing aggregation you have to use aggregate operators, with only exception the `$match` stage where you can use query operators.

Query

- alternative slightly different solution from yours using `$setField`
- i guess it will be faster, but probably little difference
- no need to use javascript it will be slower
- this is >= MongoDB 5 solution, `$setField` is new operator

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FEw3L9do16K)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"sites":
   {"$map":
    {"input":"$sites",
     "in":
     {"$setField":
      {"field":"new_field",
       "input":"$$this",
       "value":"$$this.energy_consumption"}}}}}}]
)
```

Comment: I created a feature ticket at mongodb to support element wise operations: 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-4182

Answer (score 0):

use `$addFields`

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sites": {
        $map: {
          input: "$sites",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            name: "$$s.name",
            energy_consumption: "$$s.energy_consumption",
            new_field: {
              $map: {
                input: "$sites",
                as: "value",
                in: "$$value.energy_consumption"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8b5sYihshst)

Answer (score 0):

I found following ugly workarounds that set the complete `sites` instead of only specifying a new field with dot notation:

a) based on javascript function

```
set_stage = {
    "$set": {
        "sites": {
            "$function": {
                "body": "function(sites) {return sites.map(site => {site.new_field = site.energy_consumption_in_mwh; return site})}",
                "args": ["$sites"],
                "lang": "js"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

b) based on map and mergeObjects

```
set_stage = {
    "$set": {
        "sites": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$sites",
                "in": {
                    "$mergeObjects": ["$$this", {
                        "new_field": "$$this.energy_consumption_in_mwh"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is some kind of $$this context for the dot operator expression, allowing a more elegant solution, please let me know.